# Create custom Attributes in Customer Form in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to create custom attributes in customer forms. create an account, edit account, admin forms. But every time it is not creating in database **eav_attribute** table. plz, give me proper solution steps.

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "cust_flat_type",  array(
"type"      => "varchar",
"input"     => "select",
'option'    => array('values' => array (
                  0 => 'Owner',
                  1 => 'Tenant',
                )),
"label"     => "Category Of Person",
"visible"   => true,
"frontend"  => "",
"backend"   => "",
"required"  => false,
"unique"    => false,
"comment"   => "Customer flat type",
'global'    => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
'visible_on_front' => true,
'used_in_forms' => array(
                    'customer_account_create', 
                    'customer_account_edit',
                    'checkout_onepage_register',
                    'adminhtml_customer'
                ),
));

$attribute = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "cust_flat_type");
Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
->getAttribute('customer', "cust_flat_type")
->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'customer_account_create', 
    'customer_account_edit',
    'checkout_onepage_register',
    'adminhtml_customer'
))
->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

is there any way in which I will not need to create a new phtml page for create account or other

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$entityTypeId     = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeSetId   = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "otp",  array(
 "type"     => "varchar",
 "backend"  => "",
 "label"    => "OTP",
 "input"    => "text",
 "source"   => "",
 "visible"  => true,
 "required" => false,
 "default" => "",
 "frontend" => "",
 "unique"     => false,
 "note"       => "OTP"

    ));

    $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "otp");


    $setup->addAttributeToGroup(
     $entityTypeId,
     $attributeSetId,
     $attributeGroupId,
     'otp',
     '999'  //sort_order
  );

 $used_in_forms=array();

 $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
 //$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
 $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
 $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
//$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
    $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
            ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
            ->setData("is_system", 0)
            ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
            ->setData("is_visible", 1)
            ->setData("sort_order", 100)
            ;
    $attribute->save();



 $installer->endSetup();
```

?>